# I need to modify and update a value with the press of a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I fetch data, make it an object and print it's properties. I then need to update sensor.value - if readonly is false - with the press of a button, making it go from true to false and viceversa. How can I do it?

index.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sensors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sensors</h1>
<div class="container" id="container"> </div>
<script src="sensor.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// api url
const api_url =
    "https://hf3xzw.deta.dev/";

// Defining async function
fetch(api_url)
  .then((r) => r.json()) // (1)
  .then((body) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
      const sensor = JSONToSensor(body["sensors"][index]);

      let newCard = document.createElement("div");
      newCard.classList.add("card");

      newCard.innerHTML = `<br>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">Description: </span>${sensor.description}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">ID: </span>${sensor.id}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">Lat: </span>${sensor.lat}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">Lng: </span>${sensor.lng}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">Place: </span>${sensor.place}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">Read Only: </span>${sensor.readonly}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">State Code: </span>${sensor.state_code}</h2>
      <h2><span style="font-weight: normal;">Value: </span>${sensor.value}</h2>
      `;
      container.appendChild(newCard);
    }
  });
```

Edit: forgot to rewrite the attempts I made to make it work.

First attempt

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Hey There'">Try it</button>
```

Second attempt

```
if (sensor.readonly == false) {
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerHTML = "Change value";
        btn.onclick = function () {
          change();
        }
      container.appendChild(btn);
      }

function change() {
  if (sensor.value == true)
    sensor.value == false;
  else
    sensor.value == true;
  container.appendChild(newCard);
}
```

I've seen something similar to this and tried to implement but I don't really understand what I'm doing

Comment: What  button?  And where's your attempt to update a value?  And what's the problem you've encountering when you attempt to update the value?  There's a lot missing here...

Comment: My bad, forgot to rewrite the attempts I made to solve this

Comment: put a hash '#' symbol in the const container = document.getElementById("container");
so it looks like this:
const container = document.getElementById("#container");

because you are selecting it with ID it needs the #. Should do it.

Comment: Apparently (I completely misunderstood the assignment) I have to change the value on the api itself through a put action whereas the # method only changes the values after I've fetched them